# Merge and multiply arrays into one single array

Tags: javascript, lodash, prototype

I need to create one single array from 3 arrays,

I already implemented the logic and it's working but i think with Array.prototype i can achieve the same with better performance

```
let classrooms = [
    1,
    2
]
let modules = [
    5,
    6
]

let weeks = [
   7,
   8
]

let avalArray = [];
classrooms.forEach(classroomId => {
        modules.forEach(moduleId => {
            weeks.forEach(week => {
                avalArray.push({
                    classroomId: classroomId,
                    moduleId: moduleId,
                    week: week
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the expected output:

````
[ { classroomId: 1, moduleId: 5, week: 7 },
  { classroomId: 1, moduleId: 5, week: 8 },
  { classroomId: 1, moduleId: 6, week: 7 },
  { classroomId: 1, moduleId: 6, week: 8 },
  { classroomId: 2, moduleId: 5, week: 7 },
  { classroomId: 2, moduleId: 5, week: 8 },
  { classroomId: 2, moduleId: 6, week: 7 },
  { classroomId: 2, moduleId: 6, week: 8 } ] ```
````

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a request *some time ago* for the cartesian product back in [`#852`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/852) (January 2015!). As you see, it's not implemented.

As the others said, performing a simple loop without external arrays will definitely be faster. To be sure: just benchmark it. I've prepared a simple suite on [perf.link](https://perf.link/#Y29uc3QgZGF0YUEgPSBbLi4uQXJyYXkoMTApLmtleXMoKV0KY29uc3QgZGF0YUIgPSBbLi4uQXJyYXkoMTApLmtleXMoKV0KY29uc3QgZGF0YUMgPSBbLi4uQXJyYXkoMTApLmtleXMoKV0KCmNvbnN0IGxvb3AgPSBmbiA9PiB7CiAgZm9yIChsZXQgaSA9IDA7IGkgPCA1OyArK2kpCiAgICBmbigpOwp9Ow==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) and here are the results:

```
for-loop:         175us
for-of-loop:      175us
forEach:          290us
map-map-map-flat: 465us
flatMap:          5635us
```

Exact numbers are not important here, but here's one takeaway: `for-of` loop (not transpiled!) is one of the fastest and still very elegant:

```js
const result = [];
for (const classroomId of classrooms)
  for (const moduleId of modules)
    for (const week of weeks)
      result.push({classroomId, moduleId, week});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more functional solution that uses `Array.flatMap()` with `Array.map()` to generate the array of objects.

However, I think that your performance should be better, since yours doesn't generate temporal arrays that are then flattened to other temporal arrays, that are flattened to a single array.

```js
const classrooms = [1, 2]
const modules = [5, 6]
const weeks = [7, 8]

const result = classrooms.flatMap(classroomId =>
  modules.flatMap(moduleId =>
    weeks.map(week => ({
      classroomId,
      moduleId,
      week
    }))))
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and flat. It will be more compact, but it will be very slow. Use `for` loop for better performance.

`classrooms
  .map(classroomId => modules
    .map(moduleId => weeks.map(week => ({classroomId, moduleId, week})))
  ).flat(2)`